# How to create a bridge for `eth0` in EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have created a VPC `10.0.0.0/16` and a subnet `10.0.3.0/24`.

Then I launched an instance (the default ubuntu image) with a fixed ip address `10.0.3.186`.

It boots fine and has the given address.

But when I try to create a bridge for the `eth0` after reboot I cannot connect to the instance anymore: (the mac address is taken from the instance's `eth0`)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge-ifaces eth0
        address 10.0.3.186
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.0.3.1
        bridge_hw 0a:66:9c:0e:54:0f
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 169.254.169.253
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_waitport 0
        bridge_fd 0
        up ifconfig eth0 up
```

Someone shared their configuration for centos - they run something similar successfully, but I cannot find why this config makes the container unavailable.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to create a bridge?

Comment: @CraigWatson to run LXD containers (they would run in the same vpc and should be available from inside the vpc)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't have any logs, you're effectively playing a guessing game as to the actual cause, so first-off I would add a secondary network interface to the instance and use that to set up the bridge on eth0 - that way you can access the instance and check logs to see why br0 isn't coming up.

That said, my guess at the root-cause is configuration - according to [this (albeit old) guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge), you don't need `bridge-ifaces` on Ubuntu. I would also strip the config back to basics and remove `bridge_hw` and `up` directives.

Comment: `bridge-ifaces` was added as another iteration (after I gave up having a tiny as-few-lines-as-possible config). Basically, everything there is added after I gave up configuring it. I've added the second interface, and it looks like the bridge is up and configured, but given they are in the same network - I cannot check what happens next (without losing access to the machine again).